# Postgres jsonb conditional replace of specific property in array of objects

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

Imagine I have a column `data` in a postgres table with the following sample data:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "a",
    "name": "Joe"
  },
  {
    "type": "b",
    "name": "John"
  }
]
```

I want to perform an update on this table to update the `type` properties for each object in the json array, converting them from the current text to a corresponding number.
text "a" becomes 1
text "b" becomes 2
and so forth

I got as far as this:

```sql
update "table" 
set "data" = jsonb_set("data", '{0,type}','1')
```

I understand this will update whichever object is at position 0 in the array to have value `1` in the `type` property, which is of course not what I want.
The replace needs to be conditional, if there is an `a`, it should become a `1`, if there is a `b`, it should become a `2`, etc..

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSONB_SET()` function nested in `JSONB_AGG()` within an `UPDATE` Statement after producing consecutive integers through use of `WITH ORDINALITY` keywords following `JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()` function such as

```
UPDATE tab
   SET data = (
               SELECT JSONB_AGG(JSONB_SET(j, '{type}', ('"'||idx||'"')::JSONB))
                 FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(data)
                 WITH ORDINALITY arr(j,idx)
              )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=495b0737184c31fe8074bf6710a0f2b3)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't really understand what your suggested query is doing, could you elaborate? I might have given a bad example, I don't want to replace letters of the alphabet by their sequential numbers, I want to do an arbitrary replace of certain strings with certain numbers. (e.g. `"type":"chicken"` would become `"type": 44`)

Comment: Hi @Alex , no, not related to the letters of the alphabet, but the sequential index replaces whatever it meets within the array for each extracted individual element, and then aggregates within one element by `JSONB_AGG()` as been in the original data [such as](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4745cefeba46efa3f12a5ca2fc40515e).